# Why is a magnetic needle deflected when a current carrying conductor passes over it?

Tags: electromagnetism

When a current carrying conductor passes *over* a magnetic needle from south to north it deflects towards the **west**.It is known that the magnetic lines of force around the conductor is circular as according to right hand thumb rule.But what makes it deflect?

Comment: The question has several possible answers, depending on the level of explanation you are interested in. You have the least difficult to understand already: it's the magnetic field around the conductor. Are you looking for a microscopic explanation of what a magnetic field is?

Comment: What shape is the conductor, and what direction is the current flowing? The phrase "passes over" is ambiguous. Do you mean that the conductor is a rest and is a straight wire lined-up north and south? To me, "passes over" means that the conductor itself is moved in a north-south direction.  Too much ambiguity here.

Comment: @CuriousOne.i am looking for a microscopic explanation of the electric current flow,the electric field,the magnetic field and all whats going here

Comment: That's asking a rather broad question. Can you narrow the scope a bit? "All whats going here" ("All that is going on here", presumably) is very broad indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that the needle aligns itself with the direction of the magnetic field lines. Since the lines are perpendicular to the direction of current, the needle will try to align that way also. It is only *deflected* west because Earth's magnetic field is still pulling the needle to point north. The needle will point along the resultant vector.

A pretty good explanation can be [found here](http://www.ncsu.edu/per/Articles/LunkBFieldArticle.pdf), which is probably a bit more in-depth than I was, although not all of it relates directly to the fields of current carrying wires.

This should be simple enough to test with a wire and a couple of 9-volt batteries. If you try this, be careful not to short the batteries because shorted batteries can be dangerous.